# How can I get FROM and TO times of trig on measure statement of LTSPICE?

Tags: circuit-design, power-electronics, ltspice, measurement, spice

I need to measure the voltage on two signals which have a difference of phase, so in order to do the measure that I need I have to get V1 (t) and V2 (t + delay_between_signals). One way to that is by finding when the reference value occurs and finding the second by adding the time of occurrence + delay_between_signals.

To acquire the time when the reference value occurs I use:

```
.meas tran tving trig V (vin) = 0 rise = 1 targ V (vin) = 1.5 rise = 1
```

But it gives me only the time between 0V and 1.5V. I know that is the result that the command is supposed to give, but on the error log it shows the time where the measure starts from and the time where measure ends. Is there a way to get these values?

Or even better, is there a way to get the time (and use it a variable, of course) where the measure occurs on the .measure spice directive?

As requested, here is the original circuit, the graph and the directives used:
[image: The circuit]
[image: The waveform]
[image: The directives]

It is hard to see but there is a difference of phase between the V(vout) and V(vin) waves. Since I want to measure the gain, V(vout) must measured not in the same time as V(vin), but in t + delay_between_signals.

Comment: The ```.meas``` now only triggers on V(vin) for ```trig``` as well as ```targ```. Is it a typo?

Comment: How are V1(t) and V2(t) produced? Just voltage sources? Can you show a schematic (in the original question)?

Comment: The .meas triggering only V(vin) is not a typo. I thought on doing this to get the time where the measure occurred, but without success.

Comment: V1 and V2 are the IN and OUT of a wien bridge oscillator, which is intended to generate a sinusoidal-like wave.

Comment: Could you make more clear what you *exactly* want? You ask for the time delay, but later you mention the gain. If your signal was not clipping, you can get the gain in different way. I may have an answer that can show the gain as **plottable variable**. (And maybe the phase difference as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to measure the Y-axis at a specific time point then, for your case, you would use this:

`.meas tving find V(vin) at <time_value>`

Similarly fot the delayed voltage. Don't forget that the measurement is directly related to the resolution of the data points. By default, it's 300 points, which can give inaccurate readings. To disable waveform compression, use `.opt plotwinsize=0`. Often times it is enough compared to reducing the timestep.

If, OTOH, you need to calculate the delay between the two, you would use:

```
.meas a find time when V(x)=0 rise=1
.meas b find time when V(y)=0 rise=1
.meas delay param b-a
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a nice sine, you can also find the delay between V(in) and V(out) (assuming V(out) lags wrt V(in) by triggering on their zero-crossings, using:

`.meas TRAN delay_info TRIG V(vin)=0 RISE=1 TARG V(vout)=0 RISE=1`

**EDIT**

> Or even better, is there a way to get the time (and use it a variable, of course) where the measure occurs on the .measure spice directive?

Maybe the following is helpful:

[image]

**Explanation:**
The left top two power sources were for testing purposes, the right two are relevant: a simple 1V source and an arbitrary behavioral voltage source (ABVS) <sup>1</sup> which value equals the (simulation) time.

Below the sources, to the left, there is an ABVS which defines the **condition**: this one gives a 1 when V(in) drops below 0.
This signal is fed to the CLK pin of a COUNTER<sup>2</sup> which raises output Phi **after X cycles**, 5 cycles in this case.

Below the COUNTER there are two SAMPLE-AND-HOLDs<sup>3</sup>. The left SAMPLE&HOLD is triggered by the x<sup>th</sup> occurance of the condition defined by the ABVS. The output of the SAMPLE&HOLD is ORed to the input of the SAMPLE&HOLD to keep this SAMPLE&HOLD in its hold state.
The right SAMPLE&HOLD is triggered by the left SAMPLE&HOLD at the same moment.
**The hold value of this SAMPLE&HOLD will be the (simulation) time when the condition defined by the ABVS occured for the x<sup>th</sup> time.**
This variable is available *during* simulation (of course: *after* it has been triggered, so when V(hold_cond1) is true).

Below those components I set up a second test condition. To plot the time delay between these 2 triggers, use
`if( V(hold_cond1) & V(hold_cond2) , V(time_stamp_cond2)-V(time_stamp_cond2), 000)`
(000 is any value you want to show if both conditions haven't been triggered yet.

1) to distinguish from normal voltage sources, I marked all ABVS with a red line.
2) [Counter](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Undocumented_LTspice#Counter_.28divide_by_n.29:) is found in the [Digital] directory. Right-click on the COUNTER symbol to open the "Component Attribute Editor" window and, in the Value attribute field, enter a cycles parameter, e.g. "cycles=5".
3) [Sample](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Undocumented_LTspice#SampleHold_.28aka_Sample.29) found in the [SpecialFunctions] directory as "sample"

Comment: Certainly is a way to get the phase, but in my case I need the time when a certain condition occurs, which the A concerned citizen answer do. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Igor My answer is the exactly the same as a concerned citizen, written in just **one** .meas statement. Just replace V(vin) by V(x) and V(vout) by V(y).

Comment: If my question was about getting phase between signals, yes. But my question was about getting the time (on x-axis) where my trig statement gets the measure (and not the final value) or, even better, if there is a way to get the time where a simple measure occurs, which citizen's answer do.

Comment: @Huisman It works for leading signals, too, you'll just get delay>T/2. However, depending on what you are doing, you may want to have two time variables readily accessible for those cases where you would like to perform more operations with them. But, sure, if all you want is the delay, this can be used, instead.